# How can I detect a test payment in google billing receipt

Tags: android

When purchasing an item through google store using a test user, is there some kind of parameter that points out that this specific purchase was done by a test user?

Answer (score -3):

Yes there is. Firstly read this [official document](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)

The variable you are looking for is called

```
productId
```

Check the following code. If payment is successful then,display that product(which you define).

```
 @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    if (requestCode == 1001) {

        String purchaseData = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_PURCHASE_DATA");
        String dataSignature = data.getStringExtra("INAPP_DATA_SIGNATURE");


        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            entryFee.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            paymentButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            paymentText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            teamTextField.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            btn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            aSwitch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            try {


                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(purchaseData);
                String sku = jo.getString("productId");

                Toast.makeText(
                       CreateLeague.this,
                        "You have bought the " + sku
                                + ". Excellent choice,adventurer!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(
                        CreateLeague.this,
                        "Failed to make purchase",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this is going to be helpful.

Comment: Does not answer the OP's question.